# Firebase - can't trust OAuth returned details?

Tags: oauth, firebase, firebase-security

The short version of this question is: If you use Firebase's OAuth capabilities to obtain a user's email address, do you still need to confirm/authenticate the user's email address yourself?

One of the usual benefits of using OAuth is that - depending on OAuth provider - you can get a confirmed email address, but is this really the case when using Firebase for a webapp, e.g. with a binding like AngularJS?

After a user authenticates, there seems to be two data objects - `authData` available to the client side, and [auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/auth.html) available for security rules on the server side. While `authData` contains details such as name and email, but `auth` contains just a Firebase `uid` plus `provider`. Therefore, if I am to obtain that user's email address, it must be provided by the client, and hence can't (in theory) be trusted?

Based on my understanding of Firebase's documentation, if I were to use GitHub OAuth for my app, I'd need to do something like the following:

1. Get user's to log in/create account with Firebase/GitHub
2. Client JS retrieves the email address from GitHub OAuth response
3. Client JS "submits" this email for confirmation - could be done multiple ways
4. Email address should be saved in Firebase with status "unconfirmed" (such a field being read-only to the user)
5. I need my own server-side logic to process such email submissions and send a confirm email request, e.g. through something like Mandrill
6. I need additional server-side logic to receive the clicked confirmation and mark the email address as "confirmed" in Firebase

Therefore Firebase can help me with steps 1-3, but steps 4-6 need to be done via my own server-side code?

The answer to this question is therefore a Yes/No, but with some justification/explanation!

Comment: Yes. This all looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kato for confirming my assumptions in the question were correct, so I'll explicitly provide this as an answer, as well as provide an alternative I hadn't thought of.

So the short answer is, "Yes, you need to obtain or verify the user's email yourself when using Firebase OAuth", and the steps I listed above is one way.

An alternate approach that still requires server-side code but *doesn't* require emailing, would be to have the user write their token to their users table entry and then have server side code use that to retrieve the verified email address from the provider themselves. e.g. with a GitHub authorization token and appropriate scope, you can retrieve the user's verified email and not then need them to verify it to you again.